# Operator '+' cannot be applied to types 'number[]' : How could I correct the build error?

Tags: javascript, typescript

The following function generates `uuidv4` strings.

```js
function uuidv4() {
  return ([1e7] + -1e3 + -4e3 + -8e3 + -1e11).replace(/[018]/g, c =>
    (
      c ^
      (crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(1))[0] & (15 >> (c / 4)))
    ).toString(16)
  );
}
console.log(uuidv4());
```

With typescript, when I try to build, I get an error saying:

```
TS2365: Operator '+' cannot be applied to types 'number[]' and '-1000'.
```

How could I have the same function build successfully with typescript?

Comment: `[1e7]` is an array with a single number in it. Using the `+` will implicitly convert it to a string. If you do want that or don't want that, there are way more explicit ways to go about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a minification technique. Evaluate the whole expression there (the `([1e7] + -1e3 + -4e3 + -8e3 + -1e11)`), and you get the string

```
10000000-1000-4000-8000-100000000000
```

So, just use that instead, rather than relying on coercion (which Typescript is not happy with):

```js
function uuidv4() {
    return ("10000000-1000-4000-8000-100000000000").replace(/[018]/g, c =>
        (
        c ^
        (crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(1))[0] & (15 >> (c / 4)))
        ).toString(16)
    );
}
console.log(uuidv4());
```

At this point, you could also replace all the non-fours (the ones) with zeros, if you wanted, they don't serve any purpose now.